# LXML add an element into root

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, lxml

Im trying to take two elements from one file (file1.xml), and write them onto the end of another file (file2.xml).  I am able to get them to print out, but am stuck trying to write them onto file2.xml! Help !

```
filename = "file1.xml"
appendtoxml = "file2.xml"
output_file = appendtoxml.replace('.xml', '') + "_editedbyed.xml"
parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
tree = etree.parse(filename, parser)
etree.tostring(tree)
root = tree.getroot()


a = root.findall(".//Device")
b = root.findall(".//Speaker")



for r in a:
    print etree.tostring(r)
for e in b:
    print etree.tostring(e)

NewSub = etree.SubElement (root, "Audio(just writes audio..")
print NewSub
```

I want the results of a, b to be added onto the end of outputfile.xml in the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Parse both the input file and the file you wish to append to.
- Use [`root.append(elt)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.append) to append Element, `elt`, to `root`.
- Then use [`tree.write`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write) to write the new tree to a file (e.g. `appendtoxml`):

Note: The links above point to documentation for `xml.etree` from the standard
library. Since `lxml`'s API tries to be compatible with the standard library's
`xml.etree`, the standard library documentation applies to `lxml` as well (at
least for these methods). See http://lxml.de/api.html for information on where
the APIs differ.

---

```
import lxml.etree as ET
filename = "file1.xml"
appendtoxml = "file2.xml"
output_file = appendtoxml.replace('.xml', '') + "_editedbyed.xml"

parser = ET.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
tree = ET.parse(filename, parser)
root = tree.getroot()

out_tree = ET.parse(appendtoxml, parser)
out_root = out_tree.getroot()
for path in [".//Device", ".//Speaker"]:
    for elt in root.findall(path):
        out_root.append(elt)

out_tree.write(output_file, pretty_print=True)
```

---

If `file1.xml` contains

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<Speaker>boozhoo</Speaker>
<Device>waaboo</Device>
<Speaker>anin</Speaker>
<Device>gigiwishimowin</Device>
</root>
```

and `file2.xml` contains

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<Speaker>jubal</Speaker>
<Device>crane</Device>
</root>
```

then `file2_editedbyed.xml` will contain

```
<root>
  <Speaker>jubal</Speaker>
  <Device>crane</Device>
  <Device>waaboo</Device>
  <Device>gigiwishimowin</Device>
  <Speaker>boozhoo</Speaker>
  <Speaker>anin</Speaker>
</root>
```

Comment: For me I get AttributeError object has no attribute 'append'? :(